# What is the best AI technique to find the best solution among a set of solutions?

Tags: sorting, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

We are doing a research on the topic "Smart Hike App". In this we are letting users of the app to register as members of our social network. When they go on a hike they can save information of their hike as GPS data, GPS map, Photos and other data. Later the hiker can upload his hike data in to social network as a story. It is a new hike with new data (May be a route taken by other hikers but new data). Other members of the social network can comment, react, and rate the story according to different aspects like natural beauty, adventure, risky, etc. In this way there will be a set of stories for a hike to a same place.

What I intend to do is to sort these stories from best to worst according to comments, reactions, and ratings of members.

Our teacher suggests that we should use Genetic Algorithms to sort these paths. As I am new to this I can not understand whether AI is needed for this. We are not suggesting new routes for users, we just show the best path.

Does this problem need to be solved with some AI technique? If so what is it?

Comment: This kind of question is suitable for https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "we just show the best path". You say you aren't suggesting new routes, but what ARE you suggesting. The best path between two given poitns (start, end) by the user?

Comment: no we are suggesting the best route from the routes taken by another hiker. We are not going to make a route.